# Optimal memory and time solution to producer-consumer problem with large data items

Tags: multithreading, memory, concurrency, deadlock, producer-consumer

I'm writing a multi-threaded producer-consumer C program, where the two types of threads communicate data items by means of a thread-locked queue data structure. The data items are pointers which point to memory blocks that are large. For efficiency, I want a producer to be able to reuse the memory of an item after a consumer has processed it, meaning the consumer will not spend time freeing memory after processing an item, and producer will not spend time allocating new memory. Does anyone have experience solving this problem, or seen a solution in the literature?

Currently, I'm planning to use two queues. Queue 1 will contain the items to be processed - producers will write into and consumers will read from this queue. Queue 2 will contains items already processed and whose memory can be reused - consumers will write into and producers will read from this queue. The program will kick off with a fixed number of items in Queue 2, which will also limit the total memory used. Is this the most efficient, deadlock-free solution given the constraints? If not, what would be a better solution?

Comment: Look into the concept of a "memory pool"

Comment: I am indeed using a memory pool. I not only want to limit memory usage, but also minimize memory reallocation, copies, etc.

Comment: Data pools can make allocation/deallocation faster since they only have to track one object size.

Comment: Off the cuff, it sounds like you want a bounded circular buffer.

Comment: @gct wouldn't repeated calls to heap lead to fragmentation?

Comment: No you pre-allocate space for eg: N objects and allocate and deallocate from that space, very fast.

Comment: I've solved the producer-consumer problem exactly the same way you've described. I've used it in a dedupe file system on a storage server. Yes it is deadlock free and it is the most efficient way of implementing the solution. My storage service remains up for months without causing any memory fragmentation, because of pre allocation of all the required buffers. You're on right track.